# how to resize collection view cell text

Tags: ios, swift, text, resize, uicollectionviewcell

I am working with collection views in my app. I currently have them resize, dependent on the size class. This works, but how to I resize the text inside them (shrink) to fit cell size. note: I do not want to resize the cell. only the text normally I would do this inside autoshrink -> minimumfontsize -> 1 but this doesn't seem to work in collection view cells. I'm kind of a newbee so please explain thoroughly. thanks for any help

Comment: you should show some code.

Comment: Check out http://beckyhansmeyer.com/2015/04/09/autoshrinking-text-in-a-multiline-uilabel/

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work. When it creates coppies (with user entered text) It doesn't contain to the cell size